# What could cause an open file dialog window in Tkinter/Python to be really slow to close after the user selects a file?

Tags: python, macos, python-3.x, tkinter

I can do the following in my program to get a simple open file dialog and print the selected file path.  Unfortunately it doesn't go away right away when the user selects the file, and stays around for over 5 minutes.  **How do I make the window disappear immediately once a selection has been made before executing more python code**?  After the Tkinter code I do try to import some video using OpenCV which I think may be causing the slowing.  My OpenCV code does execute properly and I don't think there is a problem with that alone (i.e. some interaction is causing the error & maybe some intensive process is started before Tkinter wraps up its GUI dialog).

```
import Tkinter as Tk
import cv2
from tkFileDialog import askopenfilename
root = Tk.Tk()
root.withdraw() # we don't want a full GUI, so keep the root window from appearing
filename = askopenfilename() # show an "Open" dialog box and return the path to the selected file
print(filename)

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('video.mp4')   # this works just fine
```

I am using Python 2.7 and Mac OS X 10.9 if that is useful.

[EDIT: This does not seem to be a problem for all, but it is for me, so I am changing the question to also include debugging the problem.  I don't want anything to execute until the Tkinter open file dialog window is done closing in the GUI.  It seems that a subsequent step in my program (an open cv video import) could somehow be causing Tkinter to slow things down, so I want to ensure it does close before any new process is started.  Again, the Tkinter window does actually close after 5 minutes...]

Comment: The dialog goes away for me. When the dialog shows up, are you clicking on the "open" button? Clicking on "open" or double-clicking a file should make the dialog go away.

Comment: Hmm - it doesn't go away for me.  Any idea how to debug?

Comment: After your edit, it sounds like you aren't giving the event loop a chance to process all events. What happens if you call `root.update()` after getting the filename?

Comment: Same thing unfortunately

Comment: What happens when you comment out the video capture call?

Answer (score 17):

I was having some trouble with Tkinter dialog boxes. Like you, the dialog just sat there after I had selected a file. I didn't try leaving it for very long, it may have disappeared after 5 minutes as you said your's did. After lots of random experimentation I found that calling `root.update()` **before** the `askopenfilename()` line seemed to fix it.

For reference, this is the code I was testing with:

```
import sys
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog

#instantiate a Tk window
root = Tk()

#set the title of the window
root.title('Tk test')

# I don't know, what this does, but it fixes askopenfilename if I use it.
root.update()

print(filedialog.askopenfilename(title='dialogue? surely.'))
```

Comment: Not working for me on OSX and python2. Dialog is still present while I process the input file. **EDIT:** Calling `root.update()` _after_ `askopenfilename()` works, however.

Comment: tkinter on mac appears to be waiting on the event loop. In a 'full-fledged' tkinter app this would happen as a matter of course, but in this context of a console script that's not using the main window, root.update() is required (after the askopenfilename() call) to kick the event loop, allowing the dialog box to complete its action and close.

I don't know why this is different on macOS vs Windows

Comment: It would be interesting to explain why it has to be before (on macos and Python3 at least).

Comment: Worked for me, Ubuntu 18.04. Also fixed random latency taking place before dialog appears, after askdirectory() has been called. Very useful answer.

Answer (score 3):

Exactly the problem I had - sometimes the file dialog would go away after a while, sometimes not.   But it always seemed to block a later status windows.   Adding the root.update() fixed both problems immediately.