# Tkinter askopenfilename() won't close

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm using the following code snippet to open a file chooser dialog box. It opens up the dialog fine, but after a file is chosen the dialog box stays open for the duration of the execution of the rest of my code, which is 3-4 min. I thought `root.destroy()` would close the open file dialog like it closes other Tkinter windows but that doesn't seem to be the case.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename

root = Tk()
root.withdraw()
file_path = askopenfilename()
root.destroy()
```

How would I go about getting the open file dialog to close after the file is chosen? I'm using version 3.4.3 on OSX 10.10

Comment: Works fine on Windows 7, Python 2.7

Comment: Forget root window and want coming back ? `root.withdraw()` you lose root window can't go back !

Comment: @SDilmac `root.deiconify()` to bring it back

Comment: I'm not sure if it's different on OSX, but I'm more interested in closing the dialog box after the file selection, while the program finishes it's execution. If you add `time.sleep(10)` the dialog windows stays open while python waits 10 seconds. I want it to close immediately after file selection.

Comment: @maccartm friend, can you show me `root.deiconify()` in code ? But Thank you for warning me ....

Comment: @SDilmac to avoid starting a discussion in this user's question, simply use `root.withdraw()` to hide the root window and then call `root.deiconify()` to bring it back, that's all there is to it. With `withdraw`, the window still exists, it's just hidden. `deiconify` will un-minimize it, or in this case, bring it back.

Comment: Found the answer in another thread [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21866537/what-could-cause-an-open-file-dialog-window-in-tkinter-python-to-be-really-slow). 
Needed to add `root.update()` before calling `askopenfilename()`

Comment: @mmmkay You could probably answer your own question with a code snippet.  Thanks for posting the solution!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

For the sake of closing this question, here is the answer:

Call `root.update()` before `askopenfilename()`

Comment: Just wanted to add that for me, on OSX and python2, calling `root.update()` _after_ `askopenfilename()` works.

Comment: God bless you. I was doing this since hours