# Loop excel files' paths using tkinter and pass them to data manupulation function in Python

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, tkinter, while-loop

I have written `DataCheck` function in `data_check.py` for **data manipulation** of many excel files, which has code structure as follows:

```
import pandas as pd

def DataCheck(filePath):
    df = pd.read_excel(filePath)
    try:
        df = df.dropna(subset=['building', 'floor', 'room'], how = 'all')
        ...
        ...
        ...
        df.to_excel(writer, 'Sheet1', index = False)
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    status = True
    while status:
        rawPath = input(r"")
        filePath = rawPath.strip('\"')
        if filePath.strip() == "":
            status = False
        DataCheck(filePath)
```

For the next step I want to repetively browser excel files and pass their paths to `DataCheck` using **tkinter**, the code below named `main_app.py` works only for one file then need to restart `main_app.py` for another file.

Option 1:

```
import tkinter as tk
from data_check import DataCheck
from tkinter import filedialog
import os

root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()

def open_file(path):
    
    curr_dir = os.getcwd()
    temp_dir = filedialog.askopenfilename(parent = root, initialdir = curr_dir, title = 'select file')
    return temp_dir

if __name__ == '__main__':
    status = True
    while status:
        DataCheck(path)
```

Option 2:

```
import tkinter as tk
from data_check import DataCheck
from tkinter import filedialog
import os

root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()
    
curr_dir = os.getcwd()
root.update()
temp_dir = filedialog.askopenfilename(parent = root, initialdir = curr_dir, title = 'select file')

if __name__ == '__main__':
      DataCheck(path)
```

How could I modify and improve the code above? Sincere thanks.

Comment: `main_app.py` will raise `NameError: name 'path' is not defined`.

Comment: `path ` should be `temp_dir`?

Comment: The main problem is tkinter will close after execution of one excel file and need to reopen for another file, I try add `root.update()` as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32217114/tkinter-askopenfilename-wont-close, but not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a button to execute a function which selects a file using `askopenfilename()` and execute `DataCheck()` on the selected file as below:

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog, messagebox
from data_check import DataCheck

def on_quit():
    if messagebox.askokcancel('Confirmation', 'Do you really want to quit?'):
        root.destroy()

def open_file():
    file = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=(('Excel Files', '.xlsx'),))
    if file:
        DataCheck(file)

root = tk.Tk()

btn = tk.Button(root, text='Select file', command=open_file)
btn.pack()

root.protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW', on_quit)
root.mainloop()
```

Then you can repeatedly select files.

---

Edit: added calling `askokcancel()` on closing window.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, one more thing I want to ask if it's possible: how could I add `messagebox.askokcancel()` before closing the tkinter box?

Comment: `filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=[("Excel files", ".xlsx .xls")])`